# Arduino Uno not showing up in tty devices?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, serial, arduino

new laptop and I have never had this issue before. My arduino Uno doesn't show up in the tty devices.

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04f2:b398 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 2341:0043 Arduino SA Uno R3 (CDC ACM)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

dmesg:

```
[   79.525452] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   79.676067] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2341, idProduct=0043
[   79.676072] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=220
[   79.676075] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Arduino (www.arduino.cc)
[   79.676077] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 55736303831351D0F071
```